# Bootstrap row issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue about bootstrap rows. When the length of text is different in each grid "box", the space on the line under gets empty, and pushes the next box to the left. This is a bit difficult to explain, but check out my website to understand what I mean. It is in Norwegian, but I think you will get the point: http://speedcubing.no/example/PLL.html

As you see, there is many empty "holes" in the grid.

Any CSS property to fix this?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <h3>A-perm (a)</h3>
             <img src="http://cube.crider.co.uk/visualcube.php?fmt=png&amp;bg=t&amp;size=510&amp;view=plan&amp;case=x R' U R' D2 R U' R' D2 R2 x'&amp;arw=U0U2,U2U8,U8U0">
                     <p>x R' U R' D2 R U' R' D2 R2</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

Obviously with a lot more .col-md-4 divs..

**CSS:**

```
.col-md-4 {
     text-align: center;
     margin-top: 20px;
     margin-bottom: 20px; 
}

.col-md-4 p{
     font-size: 30px; 
}
```

Comment: add the relevant code here. that link will change eventually when you get it right and will help nobody who sees this question in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple solution would be to do this, the div's that don't have two lines of text add a break tag `<br>` at the end.

The 9th child div inside of row is where the grid start to add gaps for me, a simple solution would be this...

Example:

```
<p>M2' U' M2' U2' M2' U' M2'<br></p>
```

This will ensure that each child div is the same height making the grid fluid. Alternatively you could add a fixed height to each child div.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found adding [height: 270px;] in the CSS the easiest solution

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is, your columns don't clear quite right as one is taller than the other. To fix that, use .clearfix whenever you want to clear that column(s).

In your problem, the code will be like this.

```
<div class="row">
  <div col-md-4>
    <!--Your contents here-->
  </div>
  <div col-md-4>
    <!--Your contents here-->
  </div>
  <div col-md-4>
    <!--Your contents here-->
  </div>

  <div class="clearfix">
    <!--Second row starts from here-->
    <div col-md-4>
      <!--Your contents here-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```